# How to pass messages between java app and adobe air app?

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, air

How to pass string from java app to swf (that is inside air app) in Android ... is it possible?
Im trying to make a validation..  Java app installed in Android using something like md5(IMEI + AndroidVersion + total disk space + lot of things)(Its done)  the app will send this hash to swf ... so swf will ask php about this device.. if it's allowed will receive the rest of game..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible and will require that you create native extensions (ANE) your adobe air code can call.

### Reference

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html

Answer (score 1):

Use UDP Socket interface. Run UDP Server socket on both sides or one side and put/get messages.

Comment: hes asking about java - air and vice versa. Opening socket ports it not going to solve that issue. Especially when there are special things that only android native code can provide. This has to be invoked from the Air layer, hence communication between both air and java.